# Our own custom IRC network in our Linux server instance

Tags: linux, irc, instant-messaging

Our company needs a secure chat server. Typically a closed, protected and secure IRC network. Is it possible to set it up just like we set apache or any other server software on our own server instance. We are group of 15 people and if we get a VPS or a good AWS instance.. would that be enough? How should we set this up?

please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible. Just install centos (or whatever gnu/linux OS you feel confident with) and do a `yum install ircd-ratbox` to setup an irc server.
However IRC communications are usually blocked by company IT policies since they are usually used for botnets.

I would recommend going for jabber (XMPP protocol) since there are a [lot](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/) of server and client side software.

Comment: can we setup our own jabber server then?

Comment: I just added a link where you can find server and client side software. Yes you can. You don't need  any external services.